# cut: you must specify a list of bytes, characters, or fields

Tags: bash, cut

```
x=`sudo find /test -name  "*.php"`
echo $x
p421.php p423.php read-session.php
```

I want to cut the $x with space white as delimiter

```
echo $x|cut -d " "
cut: you must specify a list of bytes, characters, or fields
```

Comment: Which field do you want to cut out?

Comment: If you need to cut the output of `find` you are likely not doing the right thing. To execute a command on the listed files either use `find [parms] -exec some command {}\;`, or `find [parms] | xargs command` (syntax will be a bit more complex if you spaces in file names, but given what you are trying to do, likely not). Also, why `sudo`? With the `find -exec` form the command is executed as root, while `find | xarg` executes the command with your id.